# Creating ruby hash object from Rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Using `rails 4.2.1`

I want to store my `rails` declared routes from `config/routes.rb` into a `ruby` hash that I can access or render somewhere.

The hash should be of the format

```
{
  name: 'path',
  # e.g.
  login: '/login',
  home: '/'
}
```

How do I do this in `rails`?

Note: I think you get the routes through `Rails.application.routes` and maybe the names from `Rails.application.routes.routes.named_routes.keys`, but what's next?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why to you want to achieve? There might be a better solution than a hash if you tell us more about your use case.

Comment: @spickermann I want to create a `json` object to use on the front end to look up url strings based on route names.

Comment: This is what I expected. There is a Gem for supports that. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a Hash where the keys are the route names and the values are the paths:

```
routes = Hash[Rails.application.routes.routes.map { |r| [r.name, r.path.spec.to_s] }]
```

`routes` will now look like:

```
{
  "entities" => "/entities(.:format)",
  "new_entity" => "/entities/new(.:format)",
  "edit_entity" => "/entities/:id/edit(.:format)",
  "entity" => "/entities/:id(.:format)"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to do this, you can:

```
ri = ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesInspector.new([])
result = ri.send :collect_routes, Rails.application.routes.routes
```

The result will be an array of hashes which look like:

```
{:name=>"product", :verb=>"GET", :path=>"/products/:id(.:format)", :reqs=>"products#show", :regexp=>"^\\/products\\/([^\\/.?]+)(?:\\.([^\\/.?]+))?$"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the [JS-Routes](https://rubygems.org/gems/js-routes) gem that generates a javascript file that defines all Rails named routes as javascript helpers.

Setup (just add it to the asset pipeline):

```
# add to your application.js
/*
= require js-routes
*/
```

Usage your javascript code like this:

```
Routes.users_path()                   // => "/users"
Routes.user_path(1)                   // => "/users/1"
Routes.user_path(1, {format: 'json'}) // => "/users/1.json"
```

Find the documentation here: https://github.com/railsware/js-routes#usage

Comment: +1 Going to have to pick another answer that answered the question more precisely, but this definitely helped me deal with my problem.